# How do I fix this problem creating an Image object in MongoDB using ExpressJs, NodeJs, Handlebars, and Multer?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, handlebars.js, multer

I am trying to build a website that allows a user to add a collectors item to the website. It has a form that requires certain fields to be filled out (I chose Funko Pop's). I have got everything working for the exception of having the image uploaded to the index.hbs page and into the MongoDB database.

Can anyone help? I think I am very close, but my terminal is throwing a Mongoose validator error (I'll show this at the end of the post)

The image seems to be sent to my "uploads" folder successfully, it just seems that there is some miscommunication happening with MongoDB because mongoose isn't happy.

Would anyone know what the issue is? And know how to fix it?

Thank you all for the help!

Here is my code:

Collection.js Controller/Route:

```
const express = require('express') 
const router = express.Router() 
const Collection = require('../models/collection')
const globalAuthFunction = require('./authenticationFunction')
const multer = require('multer')

// storage for multer

const storage = multer.diskStorage({

    destination: function(err, file, callback){
        callback(null, './public/uploads')
    },
    filename: function(req, file, callback){

        callback(null, Date.now() + file.originalname)

    }

})

const upload = multer({
    storage: storage
})

router.get('/', (req, res) => { 
    Collection.find((err, collections) => { 
        if (err) { 
            console.log(err); 
        } 
        else { 
            res.render('collections/index', { 
                title: 'Collections', 
                collections: collections,
                user: req.user 
            }) 
        } 
    }) 
})

router.get('/create', globalAuthFunction.isAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
    Collection.find((err, collections) => {
        if(err){
            console.log(err)
        }
        else{

            res.render('collections/create', { 
                title: 'Add Employer',
                collections: collections,
                user: req.user,
                 
            }) 
        }
    })
        
}) 
router.post('/create', upload.single('image'), globalAuthFunction.isAuthenticated, (req, res) => { 
    Collection.create(req.body, (err, newCollection) => {

         if (err) { 
            console.log(err) 
        } 
        else { 
            res.redirect('/collections')
            
        } 
    }) 
}) 


router.get('/edit/:_id', globalAuthFunction.isAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
            Collection.findById(req.params._id, (err, collection) => {

                if(err){
                    console.log(err)
                }
                else{

                    res.render('collections/edit', { 
                        title: 'Funko Pop Details',
                        collection: collection,
                        user: req.user, 
                        image: req.file.filename
                    }) 

                }
            })
        })


router.post('/edit/:_id', globalAuthFunction.isAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
    Collection.findByIdAndUpdate({ _id: req.params._id}, req.body, null, (err, collection) =>{

        if(err){
            console.log(err)
        }else{

            res.redirect('/collections')

        }
    })
})
router.get('/delete/:_id', globalAuthFunction.isAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
    Collection.deleteOne({ _id: req.params._id}, (err) => {
        if(err){
            console.log(err)
        }
        else{
            res.redirect('/collections')
        }
    })
})


module.exports = router
```

My create.hbs:

```
<h1>Add a Funko Pop to Your Collection</h1> 
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
    <fieldset> 
        <label for="character" class="col-2">Character: *</label> 
        <input name="character" id="character" required /> 
    </fieldset> 
    <fieldset> 
        <label for="mediaTitle" class="col-2">Move or Television Name: *</label>  
        <input name="mediaTitle" id="mediaTitle" required />    
    </fieldset> 
    <fieldset> 
        <label for="category" class="col-2">Category: *</label> 
        <input name="category" id="category" required /> 
    </fieldset> 
    <fieldset> 
        <label for="popNumber" class="col-2">Funko Pop Number: *</label> 
        <input name="popNumber" id="popNumber" required /> 
    </fieldset> 
    <fieldset> 
        <label for="specialtySticker" class="col-2">Specialty Sticker: </label>  
        <input name="specialtySticker" id="specialtySticker" placeholder="N/A if there is no sticker"/>    
    </fieldset> 
    <fieldset> 
        <label for="price" class="col-2">Price: *</label> 
        <input name="price" id="price" required /> 
    </fieldset> 
    <fieldset> 
        <label for="releaseYear" class="col-2">Funko Pop Release Year: *</label> 
        <input name="releaseYear" id="releaseYear" required /> 
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset> 
        <label for="image" class="col-2">Upload Image:</label> 
        <input type="file" name="image" id="image" value="image"/> 
    </fieldset>  
        <button class="btn btn-primary offset-2">Save</button> 
</form>
```

My index.hbs:

```
<h1>Funko Pop Collection</h1> 
{{#if user}}
    <a class="btn btn-secondary" href="/collections/create">Add a Funko Pop</a>
{{/if}}
 <section class="row"> 
    {{#each collections}}
         <div class="card col-2 m-2"> 
            <div class="card-body text-center h-100"> 
                <img src="{{this.image}}"/>
                <h5 class="card-title">{{this.character}}</h5> 
                <p>Funko Pop Title: {{this.mediaTitle}}</p> 
                <p>Category: {{this.category}}</p> 
                <p>Pop Number: {{this.popNumber}}</p> 
                <p>Specialty Sticker: {{this.specialtySticker}}</p> 
                <p>Value: ${{this.price}}</p> 
                <p>Year:{{this.releaseYear}}</p>
                {{#if ../user}} 
                    <div>
                        <a href="/collections/edit/{{this._id}}" class="link-primary">Edit</a>
                        <a href="/collections/delete/{{this._id}}" class="text-danger" onclick="return deleteFunkoPop()">Delete</a>
                    </div>
                {{/if}}
            </div>
        </div> 
    {{/each}} 
</section>
```

My app.js:

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');

var indexRouter = require('./controllers/index');
var usersRouter = require('./controllers/users');
const collections = require('./controllers/collections')
const auth = require('./controllers/auth')


const passport = require('passport')
const session = require('express-session')
const multer = require('multer')


var app = express();

// database connection to MongoDB
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'){

  require('dotenv').config()

}

app.use(session ({

  secret: process.env.PASSPORT_SECRET,
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: false

}))

app.use(passport.initialize())
app.use(passport.session())

const User = require('./models/user')
passport.use(User.createStrategy())

// let passport read/write user data to/from session vars
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser())
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser())


const google = require('passport-google-oauth20').Strategy

passport.use(new google({

  clientID: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
  clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
  callbackURL: process.env.GOOGLE_CALLBACK_URL
},
  (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {

    User.findOrCreate({ oauthId: profile.id}, {

      username: profile.displayName,
      oauthProvider: 'Google',
      created: Date.now()
    }, (err, user) => {
        return done(err, user)

    })

  }

))


const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { access } = require('fs');
mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE_URL)
.then(
  (res) => {

    console.log('Connected to MongoDB')

  }
).catch(() => {

  console.log('Cannot connect to MongoDB')

})

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use('/collections', collections)
app.use('/auth', auth)

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);


// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

This is what my terminal is showing when I try and create a new Funko Pop Object in MongoDB:
[image]

It is saying there is an incorrect path or something. The image is uploading correctly to my "uploads" folder, it just seems to be having an issue with the database connection.

I thought it may be that the image type in my model was wrong, so I switched it to "Buffer" instead of "String", but it still showed me the same exact error. I have watched several tutorials, but they have set it up completely different than mine.

They seem to be using a something like this in there "post" function in there controllers:

```
let connection = new Connection({

title: request.body.title,
img: request.file.filename
}
```

I do not know enough about handlebars, MongoDB or Multer to be able to diagnose the issues that is happening. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

since you are using multer, change it from `request.file.filename` to `request.file.path`